# NOTAM - What means "no shoulders along taxiways" in German?

Tags: taxiing, airport-markings

can anyone explain to me what "no shoulders along taxiways" means?
I know what shoulder markings are, but I don't know how to translate them.

Are there German people? :)
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! The taxiway shoulder markings are placed beyond the taxiway borders to mark unusuable parts of the taxiway. In German you could call it „Rollweg-Randstreifen“. Do you have reference which airport this NOTAM Came from?

Comment: Thanks! Oh "Rollweg-Randstreifen" sounds good! Here is the full NOTAM: Taxiway A closed for all operations, work in progress on shoulders along edges of RWY; WEF 1 APR until 26...

Comment: @pcfreakxx I googled it. The actual text might be from http://students.radiocheck.at/uebersetzungstexte.pdf The document is an exercise book for translating phrases used in radio communications. And the very same document includes this German translation: _"Rollweg A für jeden Betrieb gesperrt, Arbeiten **auf den Schultern** entlang der Pistenränder im Gange; mit Wirkung vom 1. April bis 26. April."_ Indeed, "shoulder" is "Schulter" in German and the "Straßenschulter" (street shoulder) is the area beneath a paved road.

Answer (score 4):

The NOTAM you copy doesn't mention taxiway shoulders anywhere. It says there is work going on on the shoulders of the runway and apron, and that a taxiway is closed.

As to taxiways not having shoulders, quite possible. The hard shoulder is the area outside the marked road surface, this can sometimes be extremely narrow.